# how can I get a correct response from a rest API?

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp, rest-client

I want to send a request to a rest API and get response and show it on the form. the API documentation says that I should use my token in bearer to Authorization in the header.
 I've used RestSharp nugget and this my written code:

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.payping.ir");
        var request = new RestRequest("v1/product/List");

        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <myToken>");
        request.AddParameter("offset", 0);
        request.AddParameter("limit", 10);

        var response = client.Execute(request, Method.GET);

        richTextBox2.Text = "Status:\n" + response.StatusCode + "\nContent:\n" + response.Content + "\nResponse:\n" + response.IsSuccessful;
```

but I receive an incorrect response. my final string that returns on my form by this code is:

> Status:
>    0
>
> Content:
>
> Response:
>   False

what is my mistake? and how can I get a correct response from a rest API?
thank you for your attention

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference but try with _`RestClient("https://api.payping.ir/");`_ (final slash)

Comment: I have tried this and I got same result.

Comment: @Steve For future reference, RestSharp doesn't care about the trailing slash.  It's quite a nice package they've got there ;)

Comment: There is absolutely no way we can help you without knowing what the server is doing.  For all we know it may simply return the values you posted, regardless of what you send.

Comment: the API docements are in FARSI  : https://docs.payping.ir/

the problem is that I don't get "any" response

Comment: I get a 401 response when using an invalid token, so I believe the issue is server side. I looked at the docs and your request looks valid.

Comment: Usually these type of requests are of type "POST". Can you try changing to Method.POST ?

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
request.AddParameter("Authorization", $"Bearer {myToken}", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
```

Then inspect your sent packet using Fiddler to verify header is sent.

Next step is server-side then ;)

Comment: This should be a comment, at best.

Comment: "addheader" method is the same as "addparameter" method with hyypheader parameter type. but I tried this code and I installed fiddler and inspected the packet. in the header tab shows me this text: "CONNECT api.payping.ir:443 HTTP/1.1" and in the Auth tab shows this: "No Proxy-Authorization Header is present. No Authorization Header is present."

Comment: I think fiddler might have a problem with inspecting the headers because the request is using https

Comment: I totally agree with the AddHeader method, which is an overload of the AddParameter one. I just wasn't sure you correctly inserted your token value using string interpolation.